# Change width to full width in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in JavaScript. I need to increase the width to full width. In CSS I can do it by writing width:100%. How do I write it in JavaScript? Please guide. Thanks.

```
jQuery(document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        jQuery('#example3' ).sliderPro({
            width:1250,
            height:400,
            fade: true,
            arrows: true,
            buttons: false,
            fullScreen: true,
            shuffle: true,
            thumbnailArrows: true,
            autoplay: false
        });
    });
```

Comment: width:auto; doesn't work?

Comment: @AlexKante: I tried `width:auto` but the tag breaks the slider

Comment: And also width:100%?

Answer (score 3):

Sinse you're using slider pro 100% should be possible so width: '100%'

this is what it says on their page:

width:
Sets the width of the slide. Can be set to a fixed value, like 900 (indicating 900 pixels), or to a percentage value, like '100%'. It's important to note that percentage values need to be specified inside quotes. For fixed values, the quotes are not necessary. Also, please note that, in order to make the slider responsive, it's not necessary to use percentage values. 
Default value: 500

Comment: The only reasonable answer here. People, THINK before you answer!

Answer (score 0):

CSS `width:100%` is equivalent to `jQuery(element).css('width', '100%');` for single property or

```
jQuery(element).css({
    'width': '100%'
});
```

for multiple properties.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't understand units like `px` or `%` right out of the box. You'll want to write `width: window.innerWidth` in your code snippet on line 3. That's Javascript for "the size of the window".